# how to execute sql script after oracle docker container startup?

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I have setup docker container with spring boot + oracle DB.

I need to run one sql script when oracle container startup.

I tried below approach but container stuck in docker-entrypoint shell script waiting for database startup.

### **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  oracle:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./docker/oracle/Dockerfile
    container_name: cc_admin_portal_oracleDB
    volumes:
      - oracle-data:/var/lib/oracle/data
      - ./docker/oracle/docker-entrypoint.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/docker-entrypoint.sh
      - ./docker/oracle/oracle-scripts.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/oracle-scripts.sql
    entrypoint: ["/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
    expose:
    - 1522
    ports:
      - 1522:1521
    environment:
        - ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB
        - SYS_PASSWORD=Oradoc_db1
        - PDB_NAME=abcd
        - PDB_PASSWORD=abcd1234
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - inbound-network
# APP*****************************************
  cc_admin_portal:
    image: cc_admin_portal:latest
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./docker/cc_admin_portal/Dockerfile
    container_name: cc_admin_portal
    environment:
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_TYPE : com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521:ORCLCDB
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: abcd
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: abcd1234
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
    entrypoint: ["/usr/local/wait-for-it.sh","oracle:1521","--timeout=0","--strict", "--", "catalina.sh","run"]
    depends_on:
      - oracle
    links:
      - oracle
    networks:
      - inbound-network
volumes:
  oracle-data:
networks:
  inbound-network:
    name: inbound-network
```

### **docker-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

until echo "exit" | sqlplus -L sys/Oradoc_db1 as sysdba < /dev/null | grep 'Connected to'; do
  echo "Waiting for database to start.Trying again in 5 seconds..."
  sleep 5
done

for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
    case "$f" in
        *.sql)    echo "[IMPORT] $0: running $f"; echo "exit" |  sqlplus -S / as sysdba @$f; echo ;;
        *)        echo "[IMPORT] $0: ignoring $f" ;;
    esac
    echo
done
```

### **./docker/oracle/Dockerfile**

```
FROM store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim
RUN rm -rf /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
ENV PATH="${ORACLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${ORACLE_HOME}"
```

is there any other way i can achieve sql script execution after oracle container up and running?

Comment: Show your `./docker/oracle/Dockerfile`

Answer (score 0):

From what I see I suspect that you just need to add
`@path_to_sql_script` into your `./docker/oracle/oracle-scripts.sql`.

But I'd suggest to use official [Oracle images](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance). In this case you could just mount your directory with sql scripts into as `/opt/oracle/scripts/startup` and configurations scripts as `/opt/oracle/scripts/setup`.

Comment: As far as I know you don't need the entrypoint task in the compose file. Every script in the mounted volume will be executed by default. Also the check of the "waiting for database to start..." probably won't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you can customize your Oracle DB image and add a directory for start-up scripts by yourself.
Usually, a Docker image with a database has some bash script file that runs commands on the container startup. One can edit this script and add literally any logic to it by following steps below:

1. Run a container from the image
2. Poc around inside the container and find the script mentioned above. Most likely you will find a hint for script name and location in the container logs.
3. Copy this script to PC, add custom logic.
4. Create Dockerfile which uses the original image as a base, and in COPY instruction specify a command to copy the edited script into the image.
5. Build a new image using created Dockerfile.
6. Spin container from the newly built image.

You can follow this [tutorial](https://faun.pub/run-sql-startup-script-on-oracle-database-container-initialization-e94ea983dccd) for customaizing Oracle database-enterprise:12.2.0.1 image.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30300603)